# Styling all Components Angular from styles.scss

Tags: css, angular

Is it possible to define a style in e.g. the styles.scss that applies to all Components selectors
( app-componentA, app-componentB ...) ?

I know I could add the style to each selector individually but I'm worried that it will be forgotten in the future when a new component is added...

In short, I don't want to duplicate the code every time.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I'm looking for a "css-query" which addresses all Angular components. So some kind of wildcard like

```
styles.scss
.app* { 
  margin-left: 20px; // will be applied to all DOM elements starting with app
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try without incapsulation:

```
@Component({encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None})
```

OR turn off encapsulation globally
OR add some class for all components like compA & compB
OR in style.scss write compA, compB { /* some stiles */ }

Comment: Can you elaborate on "without incapsulation"? and the second option is exactly what I want to avoid since I don't want to add a specific class to each component...

Comment: @JohnDoe i fix my answer for more detail

Comment: Ok thanks! Maybe my question is unclear, but I still don't understand what exact css I can write to address all components in my project...

Comment: @JohnDoe without encapsulation all styles works everythere (nvm in some.comp.scss or in style.scss)

Comment: Yeah, thank you I understand how the view encapsulation works but I'm looking for a generic css that applies to all angular components

Answer (score 0):

In Your component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'compA',
  templateUrl: './compA.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./compA.component.css'],
  encapsulation:  ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```